# ¿Como usar export e import correctamente en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, condiciones, javascript-import, exportar

Estoy intentando exportar los datos que recibo de Arduino mediante serialport de Node.js como se puede observar en el siguiente codigo.

```
/*CONEXIÓN POR MEDIO DEL PUERTO SERIAL ARDUINO A JavaScript MEDIANTE Nodejs*/
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const parser = new Readline();
/*LEER EL PUERTO SERIAL*/
const mySerial = new SerialPort("COM4", {
  baudRate: 9600,
});
/*INDICA QUE SE ESTA COMUNICANDO CON LOS DATOS DEL PUERTO*/
mySerial.on("open", function () {
  console.log("puerto abierto");
});
/*MUESTRA LOS DATOS POR LA TERMINAL*/
mySerial.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString()); 
  export default dato = data.toString();/*EXPORTANDO LOS DATOS*/
});
/*SI GENERA ALGUN ERROR LO NOTIFICA */
mySerial.on("err", function (err) {
    console.log(err.message());
})
```

Y los recibo en el siguiente codigo haciendo una comparativa mediante un if para verificar de que si estan llegando los numero.

```
import datoArduino from "./datosArduino";

if (datoArduino == 7) {
  console.log("ENTRO AL if");
}
```

Que me recomiendan hacer ya que esto me genera error.¿la lógica esta mal?

Comment: datoArduino no esta definido en el primer archivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas `nodejs` no puedes usar `import` y `export` de `ES6`, en su lugar debes usar   [Node.js Export Module](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports) de `nodeJS` y para el caso de `import` en su lugar debes usar `require()`, ademas recordar que todo lo que sea un `export` o `import` tiene que cumplir ciertas reglas, como por ejemplo, los `import` siempre van al inicio del todo de un documento y no pueden ir mezclados entre codigo propio (no puedes meter imports dentro de una estructura cualquiera).

Para los exports no necesariamente deben ir al inicio, pero se aconseja tener todos tus exports en una sola parte y no dispersos por el codigo, ademas no pueden haber sentencias `export` dentro de cualquier cosa que sea una estructura (tampoco funciones), esto por supuesto tambien aplicara a la sentencia `default` (**solo aplicable a javascript, ya que en nodeJS import, export y default no existen**).

Aqui la documentacion oficial que contiene informacion acerca de `module.exports` y `require()` de **nodeJS**:

[Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports)

Dicho esto entonces lo que tienes aqui es un fallo grave:

```
mySerial.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString()); 
  export default dato = data.toString();/*EXPORTANDO LOS DATOS*/
});
```

Pues tienes un `export` dentro de un listener, lo cual es mucho peor que tener un `export` dentro de una funcion no ligada a ningun evento.

Ahora bien, debo recordarte por si acaso que `javascript` **corre del lado del cliente**, mientras que **nodejs corre del lado del servidor**, asi que espero que no estes intentado usar ese `export` para importar algo de `nodeJS` en `javascript`, si usas `module.exports` en nodeJS para exportar lo que deseas,  `javascript` simplemente no reconocera lo que estas intentando decir con `module.exports`, por lo tanto tu importacion fallara.

En conclusion, `module.exports` solo debe ser usado por archivos de `nodeJS` y no de `javascript`, `module.exports` seria para exportar cosas de un archivo, mientras que el `require()` de `nodeJS` se usaria para importar las cosas exportadas por el `module.exports` de `nodeJS`.

Otro punto del porque no funcionaria el `import`, es que tu desde el archivo que quieres importar lo que exportaste tienes:

```
import datoArduino from "./datosArduino";
```

El problema es el nombre (**datoArduino**), tu no le colocaste en el `export` su nombre como `datoArduino`, si no que simplemente le colocaste `dato`, por lo tanto tu sentencia `import` fallara siempre:

```
export default dato = data.toString();
```

como vemos se llama `dato` y no `datoArduino`.

Ademas de tener en cuenta que ni `import` ni `export` ni `default` servirian en `nodeJS`, como hemos dicho antes.

Comment: Si eso estuve viendo apenas publique la pregunta. Ya entendí mucho con lo que acabas de explicar. Muchas gracias por el tiempo y la explicación.

Comment: @SantiagoOrozco de nada amigo, recuerda que si mi respuesta te fue util puedes darla como aceptada dandole al boton que parece un chulo :3